# Listings package language Assembler could not be loaded

Tags: listings, code

hi i'm trying to do a very basic paper on asm x86 intel syntax, I tried few languages like Python , C , perl and makefile and with that i got no errors.

this is my LaTEX code

```
\documentclass{article} 
\title{Bind TCP shell} 
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{How to call a syscall on linux in ASMx86}
\paragraph{Teory}
\paragraph{Example}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Assembler]
mov eax,edx
int=X
testo
\end{lstlisting}
testo
\end{document}
```

this is the error i got
`Package Listings Error: Couldn't load requested language. \begin{lstlisting}[language=Assembler]`

Thanks

Comment: Apparently `Assembler` has no default dialect. Try `\begin{lstlisting}[language={[x86masm]Assembler}]` or `\begin{lstlisting}[language={[Motorola68k]Assembler}]`

Comment: thanks ,no error i hope the masm markup will work for me using intel syntax . Btw why don't you post as answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't select a language dialect in square brackets, `listings` falls back to the default dialect and if there is none to the empty dialect.

The language `Assembler` is defined without an empty dialect and has no default dialect, so you need to explicitly specify a dialect when you select the language. The available dialects of `Assembler` are `x86masm` and `Motorola68k`.

Remember that LaTeX usually only accepts nested square brackets when you hide the inner brackets in curly braces.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\title{Bind TCP shell} 
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{How to call a syscall on linux in ASMx86}
\paragraph{Teory}
\paragraph{Example}
\begin{lstlisting}[language={[x86masm]Assembler}]
mov eax,edx
int=X
testo
\end{lstlisting}
testo
\end{document}
```

[image: highlighted code.]